# development of $\frac{x-sin x}{x^2}$ in 0

Tags: real-analysis

I have to develop the function $\frac{x-sin x}{x^2}$ until the fifth term in the point 0.
But the function is not defined in 0, and also the derivatives are not defined in 0.
In this case is it still possible to find a function that can approximate the given function?

N.B. For development I intend this:
$$  \sum_{k=0}^5 \frac{f^{(k)}}{k!}*(x-x_0)^k  $$

Comment: You can write the series for $x - \sin x$ and then divide that by $x$.

Comment: The function has a nice limit at $0$, which is $0$.  Similarly, all its derivatives have limits at $0$.

Comment: forgive me I edited the post ...it's $x^2$

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, indeed , so when  I have to calculate the value of this derivatives in 0 what should I put if they are not defined in $0$?

Comment: Put their limits as you approach $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you by "develop" mean to take its Taylor expansion, you can certainly do that.

$$\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + \mathcal{O}(x^9)$$

$$x-\sin(x) = \frac{x^3}{3!} - \frac{x^5}{5!} + \frac{x^7}{7!} + \mathcal{O}(x^9)$$

$$\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^2} = \frac{x}{3!} - \frac{x^3}{5!} + \frac{x^5}{7!} + \mathcal{O}(x^7)$$

This series will converge to $f$ for all $x \neq 0$. If you redefined $f$ so that $f(0)=0$, the function would be continuous and the series will converge to $f$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: For development I intend this:
$$  \sum_{k=0}^5 \frac{f^{(k)}}{k!}*(x-x_0)^k$$    and I don't know how to calculate the coefficients $f^(k)$

Comment: Then you can follow this approach. In order to get 5 non-zero terms, you will have to write out two more terms than I have done, but that should be no great challenge.

Comment: @Anne Fenris is right. You wrote what you intend... And you got it! $\sum_{k=0}^5 \frac{f^{(k)}}{k!}*(x-x_0)^k = \frac{x}{3!} - \frac{x^3}{5!} + \frac{x^5}{7!}$ is exactly what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$f(x) = \frac{x - \sin x}{x}$ is indeed not defined at $0$. $f$ can however be extended by continuity at $0$. You'll see that when you'll perform the expansion. And see that $f(0)=0$ allows to extend $f$ to a continuous map defined on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I edited the text, sorry

Comment: @Anne: your new text does not clear the problem.